Data validation- dropdown not showing in windows excel file using phpExcel library
I have implemneted export functionality using phpExcel,i have added data validation, dropdown options in the excel file, when i export all data arroung 1000 plus records in windows, it doesnot show dropdown added. Same file if i open in Linux system it doesnt give any issue, works as expected. If export below 1000 records and open in windows, it shows the data validation dropdown.
Initially i thought some data issue, but if it happens for more than 1000 records in windows im not sure why this error happening.
Please can any help me to solve this issue, Im stuck in this from few days.
attached file is opened in linux
enter image description here
Thanks in advance
It should show dropdown in all OS
